# Creating an unconstructed object instance

Tags: java, bytecode

In Java, is there any way to separate the steps that happen during object creation:

- memory allocation
- object construction

In other words, are there high level constructs (maybe using refection?) that accurately map the bytecode instructions `new` (memory allocation) and `invokespecial` (object construction).

No particular usage, more like a curiosity thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no API (reflection or otherwise) for this in the JDK.  You can however manipulate byte code itself, at runtime, using libraries that do that.  For example, http://asm.ow2.org/

Comment: even with bytecode manipulation, you wont get access to the memory before the jlo constructor has exited normally.

Answer (score 2):

```
     sun.misc.Unsafe

     /** Allocate an instance but do not run any constructor.
         Initializes the class if it has not yet been. */
     public native Object allocateInstance(Class cls)
         throws InstantiationException;

    ---- 

    Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);

    Integer integer = (Integer)unsafe.allocateInstance(Integer.class);

    System.out.println(integer);  // prints "0"
```

don't know how to do the 2nd part - invoke constructor on it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing out this package. I tried getting a reference on the default "<init>" constructor using Class.getDeclaredMethod(), but no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM creates objects before they are given to the constructor; if a derived-class constructor throws an exception before chaining to the base-class constructor, I would expect that the derived class `Finalize` method will run on the object without any part of the base constructor ever having run.

Comment: Umm, doesn't the base-class constructor execute *before* the derived-class constructor?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The derived class constructor has to start with a call to the base-class constructor, but it's possible for the evaluation of that call's parameters to fail (e.g. if the derived constructor takes a parameter `foo` and calls the base constructor with value `1/foo`, calling the derived constructor with a `foo` value of zero would throw an exception before the base constructor executes).